# How to kill mysterious MSSQL Server smart-admin backups to azure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

This job was apparently set up by someone who has left the customer's business.
It spams the SQL Server Log every 5 minutes with these errors

[image]

Tracing to find the culprit that logs these, I managed to find some references to Smart Admin, which I think is a SQL Server feature for automatic backups to Azure.
I find it fascinating that the commands are fired from SQL Server Agent itself, although there are no jobs that would fire these commands.

```
declare @p6 uniqueidentifier
set @p6='xxxxxxxx-7B91-45DD-93AB-0AB7B1349543'
exec sp_agent_add_job @job_name=N'smart_admin_6c683ae3-e77b-490f-8880-291a542ee42b',@enabled=1,@description=N'Smart-admin: system job to perform backup',@start_step_id=1,@delete_level=3,@job_id=@p6 output
select @p6
go
exec sp_agent_add_jobstep @job_name=N'smart_admin_6c683ae3-e77b-490f-8880-291a542ee42b',@step_id=1,@step_name=N'Backup database',@subsystem=N'Tsql',@command=N'EXEC msdb.managed_backup.sp_do_backup @db_name = [JDMProjectRepository], @backup_type = 1, @backup_locally = 0, @copy_only = 0, @backup_file_path = N''https://mymymybackups.blob.core.windows.net/backupcontainer/JDMProjectRepository_8b1b93bc86544cdcad79460414d90fea_20230810121746+12.log'', @encryption_algorithm = NULL, @encryptor_type = NULL, @encryptor_name = NULL, @file_count = 1',@on_success_action=1,@on_success_step_id=0,@on_fail_action=2,@on_fail_step_id=0,@database_name=N'master',@retry_attempts=0,@retry_interval=0,@flags=128
go
```

It is quickly followed by

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXECUTE [msdb].[dbo].[sp_agent_log_job_history] @job_id = @P1, @is_system = @P2, @step_id = @P3, @sql_message_id = @P4, @sql_severity = @P5, @run_status = @P6, @run_date = @P7, @run_time = @P8, @run_duration = @P9, @operator_id_emailed = @P10, @operator_id_netsent = @P11, @operator_id_paged = @P12, @retries_attempted = @P13, @session_id  = @P14, @message = @P15',N'@P1 uniqueidentifier,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 int,@P8 int,@P9 int,@P10 int,@P11 int,@P12 int,@P13 int,@P14 int,@P15 nvarchar(4000)','xxxxxxxx-7B91-45DD-93AB-0AB7B1349543',1,1,3013,16,0,20230810,121746,2,0,0,0,0,23,N'Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Cannot open backup device ''https://mymymybackups.blob.core.windows.net/backupcontainer/JDMProjectRepository_8b1b93bc86544cdcad79460414d90fea_20230810121746+12.log''. Operating system error 50(The request is not supported.). [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3201)  BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013).  The step failed.'
```

Is SQL Server Agent taking commands via OLE or over a named pipe or TCP channel?
Does it have a hidden job store specifically for SQL Server IaaS Agent?

These are only side questions though, the main question is in the topic.

FYI the commands to add the `job` and `jobstep` comes from a SQL connection that identifies itself as ".Net SqlClient Data Provider", although the following `sp_agent_log_job_history` uses the normal "SQLAgent - Job Manager" ApplicationName.  All commands are fired from the local SQL Server Agent's ClientProcessID.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like someone configured smart admin managed backup, which can be disabled. The [Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/disable-sql-server-managed-backup-to-microsoft-azure?view=sql-server-ver16) article walks through all of the information and commands you'll need.